# In Django, how do you update all objects when creating a new one with generic.CreateView?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a model with an "order" field that automatically updates whenever a new object is created. (Later, I want to update it when you drag table rows around as well.)

I started following [this tutorial](https://www.revsys.com/tidbits/keeping-django-model-objects-ordered/), but I'm stuck in trying to use the manager to actually create the object. This is my simplified code:

```
# models.py

class Entry(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    objects = EntryManager()

class EntryManager(models.Manager):

    def create(self, **kwargs):

        instance = self.model(**kwargs)

        with transaction.atomic():

            results = self.filter(
                owner = instance.owner
            ).aggregate(
                Max('order')
            )


            current_order = results['order__max']
            if current_order is None:
                current_order = 0

            value = current_order + 1
            instance.order = value
            instance.save()

            return instance
```

```
#views.py

class EntryCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    model = Entry
    fields = ['name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

When I create a new Entry object here, I get something with an empty order field. Do I need to call the manager directly somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to override the `Entry.save()` method or add a signal handler to implement this. A manager is for handling queries, it's not for overriding save/create behaviour

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington! Quick follow-up: where would I overwrite that? I may still be misunderstanding when to put things in a view vs. a model class. (Also if you have any useful resources in your pocket, I'd be really grateful for them!)

Comment: You can add a `save()` method to your model to overwrite it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

Comment: Thanks! And does it make sense / is it a good practice to update all objects of a model type in a save function (e.g., in order to update the "order" on all objects if, say, one is inserted into the middle)? Also, do I need to call save at all in the generic.CreateView? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `CreateView` will call save for you. The `save` method would be fine, maybe a `pre_save` or `post_save` signal handler would do too. I would say that you should probably add a unique index on those fields so that you don't accidentally get your data in a bad state, so long as the DB doesn't allow bad data you should be fine

Comment: The "id" field is meant to be the unique index since it won't ever be used twice--at least that's how i understand the AutoField type to work. When I create three objects (id = 1, 2, 3), delete the second one and create a fourth, the ids are shown as 1, 3, and 4.

If I were to make a `pre_save` signal handler, would those go in the model as well?